# How to add a thumbnail for Google indexing in a Vimeo embedded video?

Tags: html, video, vimeo, googlebot

I have a [website with a video](https://emocoes.org/en/inicio) from Vimeo embedded as:

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/496371201" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Google says that it cannot index the video because I don't provide a thumbnail. [Google's documentation for video best practices](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/video#provide-a-high-quality-thumbnail) states:

> ### Provide a high-quality thumbnail
>
> To be eligible to appear in Google video features, a video must have a valid thumbnail image. Otherwise, the page may be indexed but would only appear as a plain blue link.
>
> You can allow Google to generate a thumbnail, or provide one in one of the supported ways:
>
> - If you're using the  HTML tag, specify the poster attribute.
> - In a video sitemap, specify the video:thumbnail_loc tag.
> - In structured data, specify the thumbnailUrl property.
> - If you allow Google to fetch your video content files, Google can generate a thumbnail for you.
>
> Supported thumbnail formats: BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, WebP, and SVG.

I have the thumbnails as PNG files. What is the HTML code to include them as thumbnails near to the `iframe` embedded video from Vimeo so that Googlebot finds it?

Comment: No, unfortunately I found no solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have a Vimeo embed on my website.

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/xxx?h=yyy" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And I also see the error "No thumbnail URL provided" in Google search console for one video page. However when I inspected the code inserted by Vimeo when the page is rendered, I see a `VideoObject` schema.org with a `thumbnailUrl`.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{"embedUrl":"https://player.vimeo.com/video/xxx?h=yyy","thumbnailUrl":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/aaa-bbb-d_640","name":"My cool video","description":"This video is very cool - you should watch it","duration":"PT3540S","uploadDate":"2023-07-06 02:56:51","@context":"https://schema.org/","@type":"VideoObject"}</script>
```

I have quite a few Vimeo videos embedded on my website (using the same view template) and have never seen this error before, so I am assuming it's a temporary glitch with the Googlebot crawler.

If this doesn't solve your problem, then you can add a `thumbnailUrl` using a [schema.org](https://schema.org/) `VideoObject` to your HTML. However, I'd do that very cautiously if you're using Vimeo because you will probably end up with duplicate schema.org which will confuse the GoogleBot more.

See this Vimeo documentation on Video SEO
https://vimeo.com/blog/post/video-seo-how-to/#include-videoobject-schema-structured-data

> Vimeo is one of the few video hosting platforms that automatically generates and inserts VideoObject Schema with its embeds. When you add Vimeo’s video embed code to a web page, the Schema is dynamically included, and Google’s crawler can read and analyze it.

Comment: Correct, my Vimeo videos now have that embedUrl with thumbnailUrl. My playlist embeds do not and I contacted Vimeo support to request that feature.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to thumbnails for vimeo, you can retrieve the thumbnails links from the vimeo API(https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos/3.4.7#get_video_thumbnail) or oEmbed(https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed/videos). Not sure as far as google requirements, separate item.

Comment: I don't need to get the thumbnails, as in fact I have them as PNG's and uploaded them to Vimeo myself. What I need is the HTML code that tells Google where to find them on my server (not on Vimeo).